# Detect when parent of node changes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I have a class that is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and I want it to be alerted when its parent changes, or scene if it has no parent node, so that I know the size of its container. I tried doing the following:

```
class MyNode: SKSpriteNode {

    override var parent: SKNode? {
        didSet {

            //code here

        }
    }

    override var scene: SKScene? {
        didSet {

            //code here

        }
    }

}
```

However, I got the error, `Cannot observe read-only property 'parent'; it can't change` and `Cannot observe read-only property 'scene'; it can't change`, which makes me believe that there are private values somewhere and those properties are calculated. I don't know what else to do besides manually calling a function every time I add my node to something else, but I feel that is an ugly solution. Thanks for any help, and sorry if the solution is obvious; I'm fairly new to SpriteKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was make extensions for `SKScene`:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

extension SKScene {

    override public func addChild(node: SKNode) {

        super.addChild(node)

        if let myNode = node as? MyNode {

            myNode.containerSize = self.size

        }

    }

}
```

and for `SKSpriteNode`:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

extension SKSpriteNode {

    override public func addChild(node: SKNode) {

        super.addChild(node)

        if let myNode = node as? MyNode {

            myNode.containerSize = self.size

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is the best solution: `parent` is read-only, there is no setter so you can't observe it with `didSet`. But it is the method `addChild()` that indirectly causes the value of `parent` to change.

Comment: why would you even bother if the only point is to set container size?  just have containerSize be a property  `var containerSize : CGSize{get{return parent?.size ?? CGSizeZero}}`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I have a property observer on it which does the actions I want

Answer (score 1):

You are setting class properties for the detection, which I don't think you will be allowed to change when the class is initialized. I would recommend checking in one of the game loop functions like `didFinishUpdate`. Then you will be able to check every frame and perform the correct operations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I just found another solution that seems to be working. What I did was make extensions for both `SKScene` and `SKSpriteNode`, and in each I overrode `addChild`. Then inside `addChild`, after calling the super function, I checked the type of the node passed into the function to see if it's `MyNode`.

Comment: Nice, yeah that is certainly a solution. Are you checking multiple nodes?

Comment: What do you mean by "checking multiple nodes?"

Comment: Are you checking if multiple nodes of the same type have changed parent?

Comment: It should check every time any node changes parent